# What are those ways to change text in textarea when button on click in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, smarty

For example right now I have:

```
<textarea style='width:100%;height:300px' id='default_file' readonly="readonly">
{$defaultFileContents[0]|escape}  // smarty code  
</textarea>
```

However, I want it to display something equivalent to (when click "next" button for example):

```
<textarea style='width:100%;height:300px' id='default_file' readonly="readonly">
{$defaultFileContents[1]|escape}  // smarty code
</textarea>
```

and with index 2, 3, 4, and so on.

$defaultFileContents is an array of strings retrieved from PHP scripts.

Edited:

```
{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="modules/Yastt/views/tpls/editarea/edit_area/edit_area_full.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

editAreaLoader.init({
    id : "default_file"     // textarea id
    ,syntax: "{/literal}{$fileType}{literal}"           // syntax to be uses for highgliting
    ,start_highlight: true      // to display with highlight mode on start-up
    ,allow_toggle: true
    ,is_editable:false

});

editAreaLoader.init({
    id : "translated_file"      // textarea id
    ,syntax: "{/literal}{$fileType}{literal}"           // syntax to be uses for highgliting
    ,start_highlight: true      // to display with highlight mode on start-up
    ,allow_toggle: true

});


{/literal}
</script>
<table><tr><td colspan='2'>
    <div style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;'>File Edit ({$defaultLang} To {$translatedLang})

    </div>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<div style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;'>{$file}</div>
</td></tr></table>



<textarea style='width:100%;height:300px' id='default_file'>
{$defaultFileContents[0]|escape}
</textarea>


<form method='POST' name='FileEdit' action='index.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='module' value='Yastt'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='saveraw'>
<input type='hidden' name='lang' value='{$translatedLang}'>
<input type='hidden' name='file' value='{$file}'>
<input type='submit' value='Save'>
<input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='document.location.href="index.php?module=Yastt&action=overview&lang={$translatedLang}"'>
<input type='button' value='Copy From Above' onclick='document.getElementById("translated_file").value = decodeURIComponent("{$defaultFileContents[0]|escape:'url'}");'>
<textarea style='width:100%;height:500px' name='rawfile' id='translated_file'>
{$translatedFileContents|escape}
</textarea>
</form>
<br>

</form>
```

How would you modify this tpl code?

Comment: you can use AJAX or just pure PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert your array of messages into a JavaScript array. You can use `json_encode` to make it a breeze:

```
$message = array( "Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3" );

// var messages = ["Message 1","Message 2","Message 3"];
printf("var messages = %s;", json_encode( $message ));
```

Next you prep your HTML:

```
<textarea id="default_file"></textarea><br/>
<button id="advance_text" onclick="advanceMessage()">Next</button>
```

Typically you would do the click-binding from the JavaScript side of things, but for now I'll leave it as-is:

```
// Reference to our textarea, build messages array, set message counter:
var textarea = document.getElementById("default_file");
var messages = [ "First Message", "Second Message", "Third Message" ];
var currMesg = 0;

// Advance to the next message
function advanceMessage() {
    textarea.value = messages[ currMesg++ % messages.length ];
}

// Call immediately to load first message
advanceMessage();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hCMs8/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to Smarty and trying to tweak the code a project. I show the template code above. Would you pleased give some pointers of your approach into the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

I haven't worked with smarty before, so do whatever you need to do to get the text you want from smarty into an array.

```
var text_from_smarty = [ "{$defaultFileContents[0]|escape}", "{$defaultFileContents[1]|escape}"]; // etc
var visible_text_index = 0;
```

Now when you hit next, call a function like this:

```
function show_next_text(){
    document.getElementById('default_file').innerHTML = text_from_smarty[ (visible_text_index++)%text_from_smarty.length ];
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dmFY/

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` for a form control, use its value property: `document.getElementById('default_file').value = ...`.